# How to set Scrollbar position in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have one gridview which was in a panel and I set panel's Scrollbars property as vertical and height 200px. Gridview has number of rows (say 1000). If i scroll down and selected a 900th row,scroll bar will move to top.I want to focus on that row after selection(ie.scroll bar will be on the same position when we selected). Is there anyone to help me?

Answer (score 0):

your gridview can have scrollbars too I think.
Otherwise try using datagridview. they are slightly different with properties.
If that doesnt work check the properties of your gridview.
Are you allowed to edit or select anything?

I think if you answer those questions the solution will show itself.

Hope this helped.

Comment: There is only one tool named Gridview. But it does not have a property to set scrollbar. Because of that I used a panel to place that grid ( panel has Scrollbars property and I set it to vertical). Panel's heaight is 222px.But there are number of rows in gridview.At a time we can see only 11 rows. Suppose I selected a row from below  by moving scrollbar below.After selection of that row scrollbar is moving to top,ie to default position. In my application I need to see that selected row.So I need to control scrollbars position. Is any way to achieve it?.